# Autocomplete with PHP and mysql for one value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

What is the easiest way?

Can I do it in php file?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

If we run this page, the output is as follows:

```
[{"label":"moen"},{"label":"omid"}]
```

And in another file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#artist").autocomplete({source: "processed.php" }); });
</script>
```

What is the problem in this code?
Write each word in the field, it shows all the values​​. 
I have this problem:  http://jsbin.com/alaci5

Comment: The problem is that you have put between 0 and 0.2 effort into this.

Comment: If you tag it MySQL at least show the query !

Comment: My problem was solved!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216238/autocomplete-shows-all-entries-does-not-do-any-searching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of problems but for starters you should rewrite this

```
$("#artist").autocomplete("processed.php");
```

in this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#artist").autocomplete("processed.php"); });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll fix it in the source code!

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize the autocomplete correctly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#artist").autocomplete({source: "processed.php" });
    });
</script>
```

And you do not include any jquery-ui css files. So if you do not declare the css styles yourself, you have to include a theme.

Furthermore your "processed.php" must use a valid format like json.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll fix it in the source code!

Comment: Write each word in the field, it shows all the values​​!