# autocomplete shows all entries, Does not do any searching

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, jquery-ui

Please help me ...
I'm a newbie! Please tell me what to do.

processed.php

```
<?php
include_once('../../dbConnect.inc.php');
$sql="SELECT name FROM artist";
$artist = select($sql);
disconnect();
$output_items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($artist))
{
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#artist").autocomplete(
    {
        source: 'processed.php',
        });
        });
</script>
```

I have this problem:  http://jsbin.com/alaci5

Comment: You can see some example with remote loading here, http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: @Hisamu I searched the Internet but I could not find anything useful!
For example, the website that referred you, no php file

Comment: coz your sql statement is looking for everything. you should have something like this in your sql statement `LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search-term'])."%'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocomplete expects the source (when an URL is specified to filter out the results).

**From documentation:**

> String: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that
>   string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can
>   be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The
>   Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query
>   string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should
>   use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is
>   set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request
>   would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be
>   in the same format as the local data described above.

So in your PHP code you have to do:

```
include_once('../../dbConnect.inc.php');
$sql="SELECT name FROM artist WHERE `name` like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term'])."%'";
$artist = select($sql);
$output_items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($artist)) {
    $results[] = array('label' => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: I do not know how to thank you!
I spent a whole day for this.

Answer (score 2):

That autocomplete function is probably passing a few variables to your processed.php page.

Use  `var_dump($_GET)` to see all the things you're being passed.

Inside one of those `$_GET` elements, you'll have the contents of the text box as they exist on the page. For the sake of demonstration, I'm going to use `$_GET['text']`. You'll need to find out which part holds the data you need.

What you'll need to do is search the database using this value for a list of results to return.

```
$sql="SELECT name FROM artist";
$artist = select($sql);
```

This is your script as it exists. What it may end up looking similar to is this.

```
$text_input = mysql_escape_string($_GET['text']);
$sql="SELECT name FROM artists WHERE name LIKE '%$text_input%'";
$artist = select($sql);
```

You'll want to get results that are similar to the inputted text on the user-facing page.

A few notes for you

1. I used `mysql_escape_string()` solely to may what you already have. While this does work (driving around a busted-ass chevy pacer works too, but there are much better ways though), its not recommended, which sets us up for point 2.
2. Using the old mysql extension is not really a good idea, its been replaced by [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
3. you'll need to escape your data, [this is how its done with mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm confused!